# Should the [row] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

The word "row" can refer to a million different things. In all of the cases I've ever seen, this tag is covered in the title of the question already, describing what the problem is. Alone, the [row](/questions/tagged/row) tag means absolutely nothing. It has to have some kind of indicator along with it to describe what they're talking about, such as [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) or [tables](/questions/tagged/tables). It seems fairly useless and meta-like. Should it be burninated?

Comment: I'm not sure that *meta* is the right word for the tag.  "Noise" might be better.  The tag adds no context to the question, nor does it help categorize it.